# How to use Like condition for Multiple numerals in SQL (Not for the alphabets)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table which has two columns with datatype `varchar` as shown below in the code.

```
create table table1
(
    NAME varchar(60),
    SeriesID varchar(160)
)

Insert into table1
values ('A1', '398,412,411'),
       ('A2', '123,516,203')
```

I need to fetch the rows based on a generated number given in the run time (can be any number)

I mean that there is a subquery which is returning multiple numeric values at runtime as shown below (its just an example for understanding the point).

Is there a way which bends the like condition to use and check multiple values ?

```
SELECT NAME, SeriesID
FROM TABLE1
WHERE SeriesID LIKE '%' + (Subquery) + '%'
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample subquery?

Comment: Sub querey like (Select ID from table2 ) it has so many ID values....(just an example)

Comment: This is not a good example.  Show us a few sample queries including positive and negative matches.

Comment: ok will do that as a new string...

Comment: Have you considered normalizing your table and storing Series IDs in a separate table instead of comma-separated values?

Comment: Your `SeriesID` wont work..just run query `SELECT * FROM table1 where SeriesID LIKE '%12%'` will return both row..event there are no `12` in their `SeriesID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using EXISTS && DISTINCT

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE
    (
      NAME VARCHAR(60) ,
      SeriesID VARCHAR(160)
    )

INSERT  INTO @table1
VALUES  ( 'A1', '398,412,411' ),
        ( 'A2', '123,516,203' ),
        ( 'A3', '322,123,324' ) 

DECLARE @table2 TABLE ( ID VARCHAR(50) )

INSERT  INTO @table2
VALUES  ( '398' ) ,
        ( '322' )

SELECT DISTINCT
        *
FROM    @table1
WHERE   EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                 FROM   @table2
                 WHERE  SeriesID LIKE '%' + ID + '%' )
```

Here is another solution using Eval SQL.NET library (allow to use C# code in T-SQL), if you need to  search by regular expression (maybe overkill in your case)

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE
    (
      NAME VARCHAR(60) ,
      SeriesID VARCHAR(160)
    )

INSERT  INTO @table1
VALUES  ( 'A1', '398,412,411' ),
        ( 'A2', '123,516,203' ),
        ( 'A3', '322,123,324' ) 

DECLARE @table2 TABLE ( ID VARCHAR(50) )

INSERT  INTO @table2
VALUES  ( '398|322' )

DECLARE @sqlnet SQLNET = SQLNET::New('Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern)')
SELECT DISTINCT
        *
FROM    @table1
WHERE   EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                 FROM   @table2
                 WHERE  @sqlnet.Val('input', SeriesID).Val('pattern', ID).EvalBit() = 1 )
```

Disclaimer: I'm the owner of the project [Eval SQL.NET](http://eval-sql.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Something like below may work assuming your subquery returns only a single value at a time:

```
SELECT NAME, SeriesID
FROM TABLE1
WHERE ',' + SeriesID + ',' LIKE '%,' + (Subquery) + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '1740|1938|1940';
```

You can then build the REGEXP using a concat ...

```
  (select group_concat(myColumn separator '|') from..)
```

Comment: I don't think SQL Server 2012 has `REGEXP` or `group_concat`.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like (using some of the information already provided):

```
declare @query  nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT NAME,SeriesID FROM TABLE1 WHERE SeriesID in (' + @Subquery + ')'
```

and you just need to generate a query returns the list of values.